# Why is `gcloud init` not displaying all texts?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, git-bash

I installed Google Cloud SDK and I'm initializing, ie running `gcloud init`, per the instructions on Windows 10 in Git Bash. However, the output text seems to be cut off. 
This is the only output

```
$ gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [viviangmail] are:
core:
  account: example@google.com
  disable_usage_reporting: 'True'
```

When I run the same command in Command Prompt, it works fine. See the full output below. But I don't want to use Command Prompt. I'm used to Git Bash.

```
C:\Users\Vivian>gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [viviangmail] are:
core:
  account: example@google.com
  disable_usage_reporting: 'True'

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [viviangmail] with new settings
 [2] Create a new configuration
 [3] Switch to and re-initialize existing configuration: [default]
Please enter your numeric choice:
```

Why is `gcloud init` not working in Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use a [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) session and see if the issue persists there.

Regarding the bash session, try and type git bash --login -i in a CMD where you have set first a simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

See if the issue persists then (using the latest Git 2.21 for Windows)